# How to Integrate a Custom Global Planner with Move_base for Dynamic Path Generation?

Tags: ros, move-base, global-planner

I've developed a custom global planner for a ROS project, which dynamically generates new paths based on certain conditions. This means that the global planner continuously produces new paths during its operation. I'm seeking advice on how to efficiently pass these dynamically generated paths to move_base.

1. Is there a way to integrate this behavior with move_base without modifying its core code?
2. If modifications to move_base are necessary, what would be the approach to ensure integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event-based mechanism in ROS 1 Navigation - use Nav2 which has this ability.

If you want to hack around it, you could potentially set the replanning rate really high (e.g. 100hz) and evaluate yourself each cycle if you should actually replan or just resend the last one.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've just now seen it. I would like to ask if my idea is feasible. As you mentioned, by frequently polling to assess whether it's necessary to generate a new path, if it is, then create a global path and publish the endpoint of this new path through the move_base_simple/goal topic.

Comment: Sure, that could work!

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tried it, and it works perfectly.